How is on/off button logic usually designed in consumer electronics?
We have a device which currently has hardware logic implemented for power on/off. There seems to be several different ways of doing it but most of them are pretty inflexible. For example, one we use has a limited way of adjusting delays. More specifically, the issue is that the on-time has a very narrow window and a too long push will set the logic back to off-state so only brief button press will start the device.
I have been wondering how all of these high volume consumer electronics implement this logic? When we first started to implement this I was certain that there would be readily available cheap, low power, small area ICs to do this but I did not find any. I don't know if I looked in the wrong places or if they are actually non-existent. It is just hard to think that all of the manufacturers would come up with their own discreet designs for them or use some MCU just for that logic only.

Why is it that hard to consider that they wouldn't just use low end MCUs for that? MCUs with ultra low power sleep mode with wake on interrupt are really cheap commodity parts.

My first approach would be to not use any hardware at all and to put the MCU (the one you need anyway, not an additional one, though they are cheap) in sleep mode. Many MCUs have a wake on pin-change functionality built in.

You can easily get push button controllers from Analog devices, TI, etc.
Most of the ICs will support setting different delays.
You can refer the below links
https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/pushbutton-controllers.html

Thanks. These seems to be the ones I was looking for. I don't know how I did not bump into these while browsing Digikey's and Mouser's PMIC and supervisor categories.

My first approach would be to not use any hardware at all and to put the MCU (the one you need anyway, not an additional one, though they are cheap) in sleep mode. With the clock turned off and outputs in the lowest power state the chip will only draw a tiny leakage current.
Many MCUs have a wake on pin-change functionality built in.
I've seldom seen an auxiliary chip or MCU used for that purpose in situations where the main MCU is a small device- it doesn't make much sense in a volume product. Some products such as flashlights use a very simple ASIC that adds features such as flashing and dimming so I guess you could consider that such an auxiliary chip.
The existence of 'boutique' chips that perform this function may be useful to you, but it's not typical of industry practice, IME.

These "novelty" ic were Maxims specialty eg: MAX16169.
But it's not difficult to develop a flip-flop for power-on that is resettable by an MCU pin. However, the quiescent current might be too much for very low power devices.
You can always run your own based on an ATTiny or PIC10 for example.

"Usually" is very ambiguous. There are as many ways used as it is possible to do.
One device was very intetesting. It had a linear regulator, 74HC14 (or HC04) and some resistors and capacitors to turn it into a flip-flop with know state when power is connected. The button toggled the state of one output and it was used to switch power on and off to the rest of the circuit with a P-FET.
Of course not all devices can handle being turned on and off without a warning so things like computers need a soft-off button which triggers a shutdown sequence and when ready then power is then cut off.
